# onPause not called when application updates

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my application I rely on onPause of my Activity to be called to perform cleaning up and closing resources. However onPause is not called when the application is updated while it is running. This could happen if the application is running and user have automatic updates enabled in Google Play.

To test what happens when updating the app I perform these steps:

1. Install app with "adb install my.app"
2. Launch app
3. Update version code of app in AndroidManifest
4. Install app with "adb install -r my.app"

App is now terminated but no call to onPause() of the currently visible Activity is performed.

How am I supposed to persist data or do clean-up like closing any open files in this case?

Comment: I don't think Google Play would force update the app while you are using it?

Comment: It will, I have seen this behaviour. The app is terminated when the update is being installed from Google Play.

Comment: And the update is triggered by auto update, not the user?

Comment: Yes the app is terminated by auto update. I'm not sure onPause() is called when auto update is performed, but when using "adb install -r" it is not called. I need to close some resources in onPause(). I also tried to listen for the PACKAGE_REPLACED broadcast, but it is the new version of the application that gets the broadcast, not the package that's being replaced..